# Module QtCharts not installed - Qt Quick for Python

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtcharts

I am new to Qt Quick for Python and I have a problem importing QtCharts in the QML file.
This image explain my whole Problem[module QtCharts not installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGDHk.jpg)

I allready verified the installation from the Qt Maintenance Tool.

Do you have any Suggestion ?

Thanks !

Comment: it would be good if you show some code so that you can rule out eventualities

Comment: Probably this module isn't installed. Maybe you have several Qt versions. Try to remove the module version with `import QtCharts`. Check your project file configuration, that should have the `QT += charts` or the same for `CMake`

Comment: The Qt default installers are not python, but, may include QtCharts if you have the commercial version. Then they're pyside and pyqt which are python modules that include their own version of Qt. Which one do you have? I suspect @folibis is correct and that you have multiple installed and are confusing the installs.